# Waiting for a thread to be blocked by an external function

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a batch of worker threads that perform an action that may or may not block. This is an external function that I cannot control.

My workers look something like this:

```
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.operation_ready = Event()
        self.status = Worker.WAITING
        self.thread = Thread(target=self.__main)
        self.thread.start()
        self.op = None

    def worker_main(self):
        # Wait to be woken up by Main
        while self.operation_ready.wait():

            # No operation given, thread needs to exit.
            if self.op is None:
                break

            # Mark worker as executing.
            self.status = Worker.EXECUTING

            # Let the main thread know the worker has accepted the action.
            self.operation_ready.clear()

            # Perform the action which may or may block
            op.perform()

            # Done with operation, reset state.
            self.status = Worker.WAITING
```

And My main looks something like:

```
def main():

    # Setup workers and operations
    ...

    for op in operations:
         # Make sure the worker is finished with an previously blocked operation
         while worker.status == Worker.EXECUTING:
             pass

        # Look up the worker for this job.
        worker = workers[op.job_id]

        # Give the worker its operation to perform.
        worker.op = op

        # Wait for the worker to wake up
        worker.operation_ready.set()
        while worker.status == Worker.WAITING and worker.operation_ready.is_set():
            pass

        # If the worker isn't blocked by this operation, wait for it to complete.
        if not op.will_block:
            while worker.status == Worker.EXECUTING:
                pass
```

Since workers can block each other if they are run out of order, it is very important that each worker runs op.perform() in the order they are given, the issue is that since op.perform() may block and it is an external library function which I have no control over, I need a reliable way to tell that the worker has actually run that function before moving on. Given this senerio:

```
main issues operation foo which is known to block to worker 0.

worker 0 wakes up and sets status to executing and clears the operation_ready event.

context switch to main, where it sees that operation_ready is no longer set and issues operation bar to worker 1. 

worker 1 wakes up, sets status to executing, clears the operation_ready event and calls op.perform()

context switch to worker 0 and it calls op.perform().
```

Since op.perform() will block for worker 0, any locks held will be held until it unblocks completely, shutting out some required concurrency and releasing the lock just before the call still has a race window similar to the one currently present from unsetting the Event object.

I thought of grabbing the threads traceback and waiting until the proper function is on its call stack, but traceback needs to be run from the thread in order to generate the thread's stack trace.

**This all boils down to: How can I reliably (no abitrary sleeps) tell that a worker has started the call to the op.perform() and is blocked?**

Comment: If I understand correctly, because the jobs must execute in order, worker 1 cannot proceed until worker 0 is finished its `op.perform()` (blocking or not), and so on... meaning that no threads may actually run concurrently?

Comment: In this simplified version, yes. Op.perform() is actually just long running, and it must be called in order, but doesn't need to finish in order. I tried to cut out many of the details of the full application since they aren't really relevant to the question. For my application when Op.perform() is sufficiently short it is better to wait for it to complete.